# Drawer layout setBackgroundColor does not work

Tags: android

I need to set the background color of my DrawerLayout at runtime.  Here's what I'm doing:

```
DrawerLayout drawerLayout = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
drawerLayout.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#ffffff"));
```

I'm not really going to set it to a hard coded value, that's just for illustration. This seems to have no effect - the background stays a dark gray color that I think is picked up from a style somewhere.  I can set the background color of the ExpandableListView inside the DrawerLayout, but I can't get that to fill the vertical space, so some of the background is the correct color and the empty space is the wrong color.

Setting the background color of the ExpandableListView in XML works, but I need to be able to change it at run time.  If I don't set the ListView color in XML, the ListView will not fill the vertical space as I want it to do.  It just cuts off after displaying all the items. I've tried setting both the drawer layout and list background in Java, and the closest I can come to having any effect is the empty space below the list items changes color.  I cannot get the background of the actual list to change.  Any suggestions?

Layout XML:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".activities.MainActivity">

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:background="@color/primary"
                app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
                app:theme="@style/ToolBarStyle" />

            <FrameLayout
                android:id="@+id/frame_container"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </FrameLayout>

    <!-- The navigation drawer -->
    <ExpandableListView
        android:id="@+id/left_drawer"
        android:layout_width="240dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:background="@color/drawer_background"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
        android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
        android:dividerHeight="0dp"
        android:groupIndicator="@null" />
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Screen shot:

[image]

Comment: Can you share a screenshot?

Comment: @azizbekian Updated with screen shot.

Comment: @azizbekian I added some clarification as well.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to set background for your `NavigationView` instead of `DrawerLayout`.

```
<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/navigationView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:background="@android:color/white"        //set background here
    app:itemBackground="@android:color/transparent"
    app:menu="@menu/menu_navigation"/>
```

If you use `ExpandableListView` inside `DrawerLayout`. I think you should put the `ExpandableListView` inside a `RelativeLayout`. Like this:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".activities.MainActivity">

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:background="@color/primary"
                app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
                app:theme="@style/ToolBarStyle" />

            <FrameLayout
                android:id="@+id/frame_container"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent" />
        </LinearLayout>

    </FrameLayout>

    <!-- The navigation drawer -->
    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/drawer_container"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:background="@drawable/background"> //set background here

        <ExpandableListView
            android:id="@+id/left_drawer"
            android:layout_width="240dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="start"
            android:background="@color/drawer_background"
            android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
            android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
            android:dividerHeight="0dp"
            android:groupIndicator="@null" />

    </RelativeLayout>

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Comment: I don't have a NavigationView.  I'll add the full XML to the question.

Comment: Thanks but that didn't help.  Keep in mind I'm setting the color in Java, not XML.

Comment: I ended up doing this with a NavigationView which turned out OK, but I'm leaving it open in case someone finds a solution to the ExpandableListView issue.